# Data models and class libraries - how to add virtual propety to object in other class library?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, shared-libraries

I have two libraries for data models and db context.

1. Basic with object

   ```
   public class Person
   {
       [Key]
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string SName { get; set; }
       public bool IsSystemUser { get; set; }            
   }
   ```
2. Extended

   ```
   public class Vehicle
   {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Plate { get; set; }    
     public virtual ICollection<Person> Users { get; set; }
   }
   ```

How do I add public virtual ICollection Vehicles { get; set; } to object in first class library. EF is correctly generating database.

Comment: You want to alter a class in a loaded class library? You can only add methods, not properties

Comment: So how do I add method?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do and use the proper terms for things to avoid confusion. You have two _classes_, are they in the same project? Then they are in the same assembly and thus in the same class library. Do you simply want to add a property `public virtual ICollection Vehicles { get; set; }` to the `Person` class, then do so and you're good to go. If you want to do it dynamically, so at runtime, things become a bit more difficult. Not in the first place because Entity Framework will pretty much not use your extension methods to create columns or tables.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have two libraries in two projects. First contains  general objects like users, persons e.t.c. and DbContext for them Second library must extend first library. In second library I want to extend Person defined in first library, so it can have many to many relations with objects in second library.

Answer (score 0):

With extension methods you can add methods to classes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> In second library I want to extend Person defined in first library, so it can have many to many relations with objects in second library.

You can extend the base library's `Person` class:

```
using BasePerson = BaseLibrary.Person;

public class Person : BasePerson
{
    public virtual ICollection Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

This will only work if you also extend the DbContext:

```
using BaseContext = BaseLibrary.MyContext;

public class MyExtendedContext : BaseContext
{
    public new DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you use `MyExtendedContext` you'll be able to access the Vehicles-collection.

Comment: I cannot compile project - if I do that 'DataModels.Extended.DBContext.Persons': type must be 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DataModels.Basic.Person>' to match overridden member 'DataModels.Basic.DBContext.Persons'

Comment: But I think it is exactly that I`m looking for.

Comment: The thing is - I allready have public new DbSet<BasePerson> Persons { get; set; } in first library Context, and there are other projects that uses it.

Comment: If I remove override - All compiles, but update database gives The type 'DataModels.Extended.Person' was not mapped. I suspect I should add somthing to OnModelCreating

Comment: Looks like only workaround that I found is to create DbSet<PersonVehicle> where  PersonVehicle has only two foreign keys in second library. Isn`t there some other way to do that?